# React Big Calendar not working with React 15.x.x

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

React Big Calendar works well with React 16 but the same code gives error with React 15

It gives error - NoopWrapper(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: Your version of React-big-Calendar might be incompatible with React-15. Try changing to a older version of react-big-calendar

Comment: What version of react big calendar do you have?

Comment: I was using v0.20.1
Switching it to v0.19.2 i was able to use react-big-calendar with React 15

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading the react-big-calendar to 0.19.2 worked, Here is a working sample with react 15.6.2 + react-big-calendar 0.19.2
https://codesandbox.io/s/70455vlnq